# Android App-links not working with certain path with query params

Tags: android, applinks, android-app-links

App-link isn't working with certain path.

For example:

```
<data 
android:host="some_host"
android:scheme="https"
android:path="test/one"
</data> - works fine 

<data 
android:host="some_host"
android:scheme="https"
android:path="test/one?user=1"
</data> - isn't working
```

I understand that this is an edge case, but I need It for mvp purpose.

Also worth mentioning, that using pathPrefix and pathSuffix works fine.
So "pathPrefix=test/one" with "pathSuffix=?user=1", but this solution won't work for all android versions, because pathSuffix was introduced in API 31.
Any thoughts on It?